# Нужна помощь в коде Python для телеграм бота

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram, бот, telegram

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, написал код (новичок в Python) для телеграм бота, в итоге в последней строчке кода

```
# start polling
Dispatcher.start_polling()
```

Мне выдаёт вот такую ошибку в консоле

```
Dispatcher.start_polling()
```

TypeError: Dispatcher.start_polling() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

никак не могу понять что делать
Версия Python 3.10
aiogram последней версии

Comment: В текущем коде есть строчка `dp = Dispatcher(что-то-там)`? Надо вместо `Dispatcher.start_polling()` подставить `dp.start_polling()`. А еще лучше, по самому скромному моему мнению - обучаться програмированию с чего-то более простого и хотя бы начать понимать разницу между классом и экземпляром класса. С aiogram вас еще async/await ой как больно по голове дадут, будете очень долго продвигаться. Раз уж нравятся боты, хотя бы используйте pyTelegramBotAPI заместо, там без async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Если это aiogram 2.x, то нужно импортировать модуль executor:

```
from aiogram import executor
```

После чего в самом конце программы написать условие:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```